# finding number of integers in a string(not digits)

Tags: java

I'm trying to count actual length of integers in a string

I've been using this method to find the length of all the characters

```
        whitespace = input.length() - input.replaceAll(" ", "").length();
        len = input.length()-whitespace;
```

but the problem is when the string contains integers greater then 9

for example "1 2 3 456" which should return 4 instances of integers.

That piece of code results in length of 6.

Another way I've found is

```
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0, length = input.length(); i < len; i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i))) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
```

but this also counts digits, not integer as a whole.

How could I isolate an integer that is greater then 9 to count them?

Comment: Does the original string contains only integers ?. If so, you could just split it by whitespace and the length of the array will give you your answer. Something like `"1 2 3 456".split(" ").length`.

Comment: Well, how about splitting your String at anything which is not an integer (or a space, depending on your possible input) and then count how many parts you have?

Comment: Make up your mind. Do you want the *number* of integers in the string, their individual or total *length,* the number of digits in each or all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String input = "1 2 3 456";

int len=input.split(" ").length;
```

This will give len as 4.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this -

```
int count = 0;
for(String s : input.split(" ")){
  if(isNumeric(s)) count++;
}


// method to check if string is a number
public boolean isNumeric(String s) {  
    return s.matches("[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+");  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(s);
    int n = 0;
    while(m.find()) {
        n++;
    }
    System.out.println(n);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this program..
`

```
int count = 0;
for(String string : input.split(" ")){
  if(isInteger(string)) count++;
}

boolean isInteger( String string )  
{  
   try  
   {  
      Integer.parseInt( string );  
      return true;  
   }  
   catch( Exception )  
   {  
      return false;  
   }  
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps

1. split the string wherever space is present .split(" ")
2. splitted string is of array type
3. now count the length of each splitted array
4. the last step is to add all the lengths(if you want to calculate the number of integers)
5. use length method of the splitted array to know the number of
   integer instances

example

```
String x="1 2 24";
    String x1[]=x.split(" ");
    int l1=x1[0].length();
    int l2=x1[1].length();
    int l3=x1[2].length();
    System.out.println(l3+l1+l2);
System.out.println(x1.length());// this will give number of integers in the string
```

**output** 4

3

Comment: The OP does not want the sum of all the lengths, just the number of integers (see his example)

Comment: @Matteo the sum of all lengths will definitely give the number of integers

Comment: @JqueryLearner The op stated _"for example "1 2 3 456" which should return 4 instances of integers."_. Your code counts the numbers of digits. (not the downvoter)

Comment: @ZouZou sorry i misunderstood the question,well I have modified the answer.Please tell me if it is right or wrong

Comment: @JqueryLearner You could just do `int count = x.split(" ").length;` (and not `length()`)

Comment: @ZouZou yes your was a simple way but for better understanding for the Op i gave my way

Comment: @Matteo Sorry I misundersttod the Op's question.Please see the answer now